# Пунктуация: Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания? Нужна ли запятая перед : "при условии"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Учитывая это, компанией было принято решение согласовать 50 организаций, набравших наивысшие баллы, на получение Услуг при условии их дальнейшего предоставления необходимых документов, в противном случае список согласованных организаций будет пересмотрен.

Answer (score 1):

Предложение, **конечно же,  требует правки** и устранения допущенных там ошибок.

В качестве варианта:

***С учетом этого*** компанией было принято решение согласовать 50 организаций, набравших наивысшие баллы, на получение Услуг **при условии  дальнейшего предоставления ИМИ необходимых документов,** в противном случае список согласованных организаций будет пересмотрен.

Пояснение

1) Деепричастные обороты не используются в пассивных конструкциях: Розенталь §212. Деепричастные обороты http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/69.htm#%D0%B7_02

Не отвечает норме употребление деепричастного оборота в страдательной конструкции, так как производитель действия, выраженного сказуемым, и производитель действия, выраженного деепричастием, не совпадают.

2) Местоимение ***их*** следует заменить местоимением ***ими***.

3) Оборот **с производным предлогом ПРИ УСЛОВИИ** в деловом стиле обычно не обособляется, так как он входит в **основное**, а не добавочное сообщение.

Answer (score 0):

Всё верно. *Было принято решение согласовать при условии...* - запятая не требуется, это не придаточное предложение. Не обособленный оборот - никаких условий для её постановки нет.

Answer (score 0):

Предложение требует правки. Например:

> Учитывая это, компанией было принято решение согласовать 50
>   организаций, набравших наивысшие баллы, на получение Услуг при
>   условии, что в дальнейшем они предоставят необходимые документы (в
>   противном случае список согласованных организаций будет пересмотрен).

Answer (score 0):

Отвечу по первой части предложения: "Учитывая это, компанией было принято решение..."

Можно сослаться на такое правило:

> Может не относиться к подлежащему и оборот со словами **исходя из**, поскольку форма исходя уже не воспринимается как деепричастие:
> **Расчёт составляется исходя из средних норм выработки продукции.**

и

> В современной академической стилистике (2012 г.) допускается использование деепричастного оборота, если он выступает в качестве наречия (обстоятельства образа действия), то есть обозначает признак основного действия, а не дополнительное действие, например: **Больному разрешено читать сидя в кресле**.

В соответствии с этим допустимыми представляются следующие конструкции:

> Исходя из этого компанией было принято решение ...
>
> Учитывая это компанией было принято решение ...